# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret' using Streamlit

Tags: conda, streamlit, pycaret

[image: Error on Terminal while running it locally]

I am getting this error while running it locally. I have created environment using conda.Python=3.8 and Pycaret =2.3.5

Please help me to resolve it.

I created new enviornment to run it and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error message, seems like you don't have `pycaret` properly installed. Do `conda list` to see what packages are installed.